# Binding Style Propety's Value in ResouceDictionary to ViewModel Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

i am trying to alter the style of my WPF-application (FontFamily, FontSize and so on). Searching SO wasn't successful. 
Within the application I use MVVM Pattern. To give my application a uniform appearance, i am using resourcedictionaries to define different styles and skins. This works so far. What  i want to realise is the change single Properties by runtime using a styling window:

```
    <Window x:Class="StyleResourceDictionariesDemo.View.StyleWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="StyleWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Style="{DynamicResource WindowStyle}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../ResourceDictionaries/Styles/Controls/WindowStyle.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Height="20" Width="75" Text="FontFamily:" Margin="10" TextAlignment="Right"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="CbFonts" Width="200" Margin="10,10,7,0"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}" SelectedItem="{Binding OwnFontFamily, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Source" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="{Binding}" Height="20"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Border Height="2" Width="Auto" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Height="20" Width="50" Text="Size:" Margin="10" TextAlignment="Right"/>
            <Slider Style="{DynamicResource SliderStyle}" Width="100" x:Name="FontSizeSlider" Value="{Binding OwnFontSize, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Minimum="{Binding OwnSmallFontSize}" Maximum="{Binding OwnBigFontSize}" TickPlacement="Both" Margin="10" TickFrequency="{Binding OwnFontSizeSteps}" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
            <TextBlock Height="20" Width="50" Text="{Binding ElementName=FontSizeSlider, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

with following viewmodel attached:

```
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace StyleResourceDictionariesDemo.ViewModel
{
  class StyleWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
    #region Variables
    private double _ownFontSize = 12, _ownSmallFontSize = 8, _ownBigFontSize = 16;
    private FontFamily _ownFontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public double OwnFontSizeSteps { get; } = 4;
    public FontFamily OwnFontFamily
    {
      get => _ownFontFamily;
      set
      {
        _ownFontFamily = new FontFamily(value.Source);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OwnFontFamily));
      }
    }


    public double OwnFontSize
    {
      get => _ownFontSize;
      set
      {
        _ownFontSize = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OwnFontSize));
      }
    }
    public double OwnSmallFontSize
    {
      get => _ownSmallFontSize;
      set
      {
        _ownSmallFontSize = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OwnSmallFontSize));
      }
    }
    public double OwnBigFontSize
    {
      get => _ownBigFontSize;
      set
      {
        _ownBigFontSize = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OwnBigFontSize));
      }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public StyleWindowViewModel()
    {

    }
    #endregion


  }
}
```

In Addition i have created a ControlBaseStyle xaml file from which every other style inherits:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:StyleResourceDictionariesDemo.ViewModel">
    <viewModel:StyleWindowViewModel x:Key="StyleWindowViewModel" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="ControlBaseStyle">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource OwnFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="{DynamicResource FontStyleKey}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{DynamicResource FontWeightKey}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource OwnFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SystemBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource SystemForeground}"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The Problem i have is that the controlbasestyle does not recognize the changes from the ViewModel Properties, and i currently don't get why. Maybe i missed something simple, i just don't see or am i taking the wrong approach to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Mirko

EDIT 1:

My goal is to change styles and skins at run time. 
The structure is as follows:
Initially, all styles are assigned different properties by a skin.
The skin defines the colors, font, size, and other things that should be consistent in the application. These can be called by their specific name (defined with x:key).
The style retrieves the value defined above the skin using the name for the currently used setter (for example, Value=-DynamicResource SystemBackground-for the property background). So far so good.

The goal is to do this with the MVVM pattern. I have defined a Style window and a ViewModel (code above). But I can't make the style notice the change.

The first question now is, can I and if so, how can I change the value for FontFamily (or any other property) at run time.
The second question is, would this approach be correct in real life at all, or are there better approaches?

example skin:

```
LightSkin.xaml:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!--Default Style-->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../00_Default/DefaultStyle.xaml"/>

        <!--Specific Style-->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="LightColor.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="LightSizes.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="LightFont.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>

DefaultStyle.xaml:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/Controls/ButtonStyle.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/Controls/LabelStyle.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/Controls/ToggleButtonStyle.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/Controls/WindowStyle.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

```
LabelBaseStyle.xaml:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ControlBaseStyle.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="LabelBaseStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ControlBaseStyle}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="150"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content}"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Every (Base-)Style inherits directly or indirectly from ControlBaseStyle.xaml (code above).

Comment: You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58371121/4448418) of mine. Try making the BaseStyle target to FrameworkElement and the setter property as TextBlock.FontSize. That should help with the fontsize.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but what I wanted to implement is not feasible, as I thought it would be at first. I have to take a different path to realize what I had in front of it.

So i am working on another solution how to implement it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *bind* the setters of the `ControlBaseStyle` to the properties of the view model:

```
<viewModel:StyleWindowViewModel x:Key="StyleWindowViewModel" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="ControlBaseStyle">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{Binding OwnFontFamily, Source={StaticResource StyleWindowViewModel}}"/>
        ...
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Also make sure that you set the properties of the actual `StyleWindowViewModel` instance that you have defined in the `ResourceDictionary` when you want to change the style.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will have a closer look tommorrow, but a quick copy paste of the code snippets didn't bring any progress. but you get what i want to do. The Senior Developer at my site, meant that this isn't possible what i want to do or it is very complicated.

Comment: What's complicated? How and when do you set the properties of `StyleWindowViewModel`? Could you please provide a [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Mirko: You still haven't showed how you modify the properties of the view model that the setters should be bound to.

Comment: Sorry for my late response mm8, i am currently working on another approach to get this solved. i will share this when i am finished.